# React native, <Text> in more than one line

Tags: react-native, eslint

I have this code:

```
<Text style={[fontStyles.transactionTimeText]} testID="timeExpirationMessage">
  Tu cotización será válida hasta las <Moment element={Text} format="YYYY/MM/DD">{expiresDate}</Moment> horas
</Text>
```

I want to make it shorter per line, something like this:

```
<Text style={[fontStyles.transactionTimeText]} testID="timeExpirationMessage">
  Tu cotización será válida hasta las
  <Moment 
    element={Text}
    format="YYYY/MM/DD">{expiresDate}
  </Moment>
  horas
</Text>
```

But in that way, the text before and after `{expiresDate}` has no blank space, and if I try to put a blank space there I get an ESLint error:

[image: er]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do something like this:

```
<Text style={[fontStyles.transactionTimeText]} testID="timeExpirationMessage">
  Tu cotización será válida hasta las{' '}
  <Moment element={Text} format="YYYY/MM/DD">
    {expiresDate}
  </Moment>{' '}
  horas
</Text>
```

`{' '}` takes care of the trailing whitespace.